# Display most recent project in concrete5

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I'm building a portfolio site for a graphic designer. The functionality is based on the portfolio in the Elemental theme (page list with thumbnails & page with slideshow and description for each project).

**On the Projects page itself I would like to display the slide show and description of the most recent project,** along with a page_list in a sidebar.

Here's how my project pages look like and also what I would like the /projects page to look like:

[image]

Can I programmatically access the slideshow and description of the most recently added project? Or can I dynamically link to the most recent project's page from the main navigation? How would you approach this?

Comment: had a look at concrete5's Page documentation. There are different methods for accessing a pages attributes. Is there a way to loop through all the sub-pages of a page and then get the most recently added one?

Answer (score 0):

as per your desc. it seams that you want that you want to show most recent project or article to previous . so i think you just need to 'ORDER BY ID DESC' in your selct query. eg SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC

best of luck.. :)

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for. To further clarify, here's what I'd like to achieve.

1. user clicks on the navigation link for 'projects'
2. user is taken to the page /index.php/projects
3. in the right sidebar of this page, there is a page list listing all projects. this is working.
4. on the left side of the page, I'd like to **show the slideshow and description belonging to the most recent project.*

I've been able to modify a page list to only display the most recently featured project. but this only displays the thumbnail image and a link to the page of this project.